# Replacing element of a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have an `std::vector` of objects. How do I replace the element at index i, while ensuring the destructor of the object that currently resides there gets called? Can I just do:

```
std::vector<myClass> V;

V.push_back(getObj());
V[0] = getAnotherObj(); // Will the current V[0]'s destructor be called?
```

Specifically, what would happen if I have a vector of vectors?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> V;
V.push_back(getARandomVector(10));
V[0] = getARandomVector(5); // Will the current V[0] vector be cleared or destroyed? If not, will I have a memory leak?
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see.

Comment: `V[i] = something;` will call `MyClass::operator=(something)`; that's unlikely to invoke a destructor, but it should Do the Right Thing. None of this has anything to do with the vector, though.

Comment: The "vector of vectors" is not a special case, your second question is exactly the same as asking what happens in `vector<int> W = getARandomVector(10); W = getARandomVector(5);`

Comment: @M.M I understand better now based on your comments to @Alex Lop's question. So, depending on the implementation of operator=, the existing elements of `V[0]` or `W` could either be destroyed or some of them could have their contents replaced by the elements of the rvalue vector. In either case, I don't need to explicitly free the memory of the lvalue vector before assignment.

Comment: @RaviR Yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<myClass> V;

V.push_back(getObj());
V[0] = getAnotherObj(); // Will the current V[0]'s destructor be called?
```

If you think the distructor will be called then you probably expect that the copy constructor will be called right after it. However it is not how it is expected to behave. There are two rules:

1. If a new object has to be created before the copying can occur, the copy constructor is used.
2. If a new object does not have to be created before the copying can occur, the assignment operator is used.

So the distructor is not expected to be called. There is no reason to destroy the object and then create another one of the same type again.

**EDIT:**

Since the question has been edited and there is now this part:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> V;
V.push_back(getARandomVector(10));
V[0] = getARandomVector(5); // Will the current V[0] vector be cleared or destroyed? If not, will I have a memory leak?
```

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/)

> copy (1)              `vector& operator= (const vector& x);`
>
> move (2)              `vector& operator= (vector&& x);`
>
> initializer list (3)  `vector& operator= (initializer_list<value_type> il);`
>
> The copy assignment (1) copies all the elements from x into the
>   container (with x preserving its contents).
>
> The move assignment (2) moves the elements of x into the container (x
>   is left in an unspecified but valid state).
>
> The initializer list assignment (3) copies the elements of il into the
>   container.
>
> The container preserves its current allocator, except if the allocator
>   traits indicate that x's allocator should propagate. This allocator is
>   used (through its traits) to allocate and deallocate storage if a
>   reallocation happens, and to construct or destroy elements, if needed.
>
> **Any elements held in the container before the call are either assigned**
>   **to or destroyed.**

Comment: I edited my question to ask specifically about a vector of vectors. It is not clear to me why "there is no reason to destroy the object" in this case. What will happen to the existing vector at V[0]?

Comment: @RaviR it gets assigned to using the assignment operator, as explained in this answer

Comment: @M.M Nobody is answering my specific question, or am I missing something obvious. In the specific vector of vector examples I provided, will the elements of the vector that is at V[0] be freed or will there be a memory leak? It is not clear from the above answer.

Comment: @RaviR there is no memory leak. Some of the elements will be freed, if `V[0]` had more elements than the new vector being assigned. The other elements will be *assigned to* using the *assignment operator*. This has been said several times now. What do you find unclear about the assignment operator? Do you understand what `a = b;` does when `a` and `b` are both `myClass` objects?

Comment: @AlexLop misread your answer as the OP has since updated the question. Redacted comment. Have an uptick.

Comment: @M.M I see from [here](http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html) that the assignment operator is responsible for deleting any member pointers. So, doesn't that mean that the assignment operator of std::vector will ensure that the memory that V[0] is pointing to will be freed?

Comment: @RaviR `V[0]` is an element of the vector, it is not a pointer. The page you are reading is talking about how to write the `operator=` function for a class which contains pointers. However it is only talking about one possible way to write that function.  `std::vector::operator=` does not necessarily free its memory and allocate new memory; it re-uses the existing memory unless the new contents are too big to fit in the space it already has allocated.  (I am describing copy assignment here. For move assignment the vector will just take over memory of the other vector).

Comment: @RaviR I edited my answer, hope now it fully answers your question.

Comment: @M.M  edited my answer, hope now it fully answers RaviR question.

Comment: @WhozCraig  edited my answer, hope now it fully answers RaviR question.

Comment: @AlexLop. `assign()` is not equivalent to the assignment operator, so unfortunately all this new stuff doesn't apply. The behaviour of assignment is defined in Table 96 in C++14 [container.requirements.general].  The elements of `V[0]` might not be erased; they may all be updated by having their `operator=` called.  (However OP's code calls the move-assignment operator so in his last example the entire vector would be moved).

Comment: @M.M but what will happen with the elements of `V[0]` at positions 5..9? They have to be erased.

Comment: what are positions 5-9? We don't have any concrete vector sizes in this example

Comment: @M.M take a look at the edited question. He create vector of vectors `v`. Then creates a vector of size 10 and pushes it into `v`. After it he assigns vector of size 5 to `v[0]`.

Comment: We don't know that `getARandomVector(10)` returns a vector of size 10. Let's assume it does, and also that `getARandomVector(5)` returns a vector of size 5. Then `V[0] = getARandomVector(5);` will most likely destroy all the objects in `V[0]` and `V[0]` will take over the memory of the returned vector (this is *move assignment*).

Comment: @M.M I completely agree but what if `getRandomVector` takes ownership of the allocated vector (which is unlikely but can be) and returns a reference? Then the *copy assignment* should be applied...

Comment: The only thing the standard defines for `vector::operator=` is that afterwards we have the two sides both being equal as tested by `==`.  So one approach would be that it could do individual `operator=` on the first 5 elements, and then destruct the other elements.  Another approach would be to destruct all elements and copy-construct a new set.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` manages the memory and lifetime of objects in its possession. It holds them as *value* types.

If `v` is a `std::vector<T>`, then `v[0] = x` is going to have a similar effect as if you had `T t;` declared as a local variable in your function, and then wrote `t = x`. `t` is *not* going to be destroyed, what's going to happen is the copy assignment operator will be called. And when `t` goes out of scope, the destructor will be called then.

`std::vector` *will* call the destructors of your objects when it gets destroyed, or when it gets enlarged enough that it must allocate new storage. Then it will copy / move them into the new storage and destroy the old ones.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. When I do `v[0] = x`, how can it be equivalent to `T t; x = t;`, since `v[0]` is not being involved at all?

Comment: What I mean is that it has a similar effect on the object `v[0]` as it would on the object `t`. Sorry, there was a typo in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure destruction and reconstruction you could use placement new and delete:

```
V[0].~myClass();
new(&V[0]) myClass(getAnotherObj());
```

However this is probably a bad idea. `V[0] = getAnotherObj();` produces the same end result and is a lot simpler.